# Why does this simple Analytics tag break my infinite scroll script?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-analytics, infinite-scroll

I'm using endless scroll to guide my readers to the next blog article. In order to count all these dynamic page views, I tried to add this simple Google Analytics tag to every article being loaded:

```
<script>

// Function to track a virtual page view
function gaTrack(path, title) {
  ga('set', { page: path, title: title });
  ga('send', 'pageview');
}

// Track a virtual page
gaTrack('<?php the_permalink(); ?>', '<?php the_title(); ?>');

</script>
```

However, this stops further articles from being loaded with Ajax. Without this tag, everything works fine. Can anyone see whats wrong with the script?

Comment: We need to see the code of `the_permalink();` and `the_title();`.

Comment: This is a Wordpress function to add the article URL and the title, to make Google Analytics track page URL + title correctly.